# Rails new GEM_HOME

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I recently upgraded to Ruby 1.8.7 (had an issue with 1.9.2) and had to reinstall RubyGems.  Now my project can't see any of the old gems in my GEM_HOME, is there a way to point my new gem binary to my previous GEM_HOME?  I can't find anything online and it's a big pain to install them all again one by one.  I'm also on a Mac, so it's at:

`$ echo $GEM_HOME

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/`

Thank you!

Comment: plus now gem install runs very, very slowly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maintaing ruby version and gems is a PITA, this is why rvm (ruby version manager) was created. It's a life savor, to me at least(I'm on a mac too). Check out rvm at http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Maybe you didn't want a "reinstall" answer, but IMHO rvm is the smartest choice.

if you need some rvm tips, check this SO out [rvm tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709313/how-to-manage-multiple-gemsets-and-ruby-versions-with-rvm)

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's just the way it is.  Glad I'm not missing something at least.