# How to install a Rails application when using RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've followed instructions from [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709313/how-to-manage-multiple-gemsets-and-ruby-versions-with-rvm) to set up RVM, rubies and gem lists.

I have created rubies 1.8.7 and 1.9.3. For the ruby 1.8.7 I have created a gemset called Organisator.

I have activated the 1.8.7 ruby and gemset "Organisator".

I navigated to the folder of my app and tried to run **bundle install**. I assume that's how I'm supposed to install the gems needed for my app, same way I did when I did not have RVM.

Error message I get:

```
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/user/RoR/testapp# bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please include the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/1.8/net/https.rb:102
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p358/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:447:in `ssl'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:216:in `connection_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:358:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:135:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:163:in `fetch_dependency_remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:122:in `fetch_remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/source.rb:234:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/source.rb:232:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/source.rb:165:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/source.rb:70:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:86:in `materialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:127:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:122:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:48:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:12:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/gems/bundler-1.1.2/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@organizators/bin/bundle:19
```

I also get an error message when I try to create a new app:

```
root@user-VirtualBox:/home/user/RoR# rails new testapp
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30:in `require': no such file to load -- active_support (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator.rb:30
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/bin/rails:16
```

I assume I've done something wrong when setting up RVM.
The only idea I have right now is installing all the gems from my gemfile and adding them to gemfile manually.

Versions

- Ruby 1.8.7-p358
- Rails 2.3.1.4
- RVM 1.10.3
- Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: does `rvm list` work right for you, and if so, what does it show?

Comment: rvm rubies ruby-1.8.7-p358 [i686] ruby-1.9.3-p125 [i686]

Comment: you might be missing certain ssl packages, refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642368/why-require-mongo-gives-me-loaderror-no-such-file-to-load-openssl

Comment: rvm needs to be packaged with ssl when installing on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use the "quick fix" from here https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

you have to ignore the rest of instructions, they are intended for systems that do not support packages (like osx)